# How to find and count how many files contain a certain word?

Tags: bash, command-line

I am supposed to find and display the count of the number of files that contain the word carrot (case ignored)

So far this is what I have, I am just not sure how to add the wc into it to count how many files there are that have the word carrot

> find . -exec grep -i carrot {} \;

Comment: How would I do it using the find command? Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Why do you want to use find? `grep -r` is recursive.

Answer (score 15):

First of all, as others have said, there is no reason to use `find`, just use recursive `grep`:

```
grep -irm 1 carrot . | wc -l
```

The `-m 1` ensures that `grep` will stop searching each file after the first match. Without it, you are not counting the number of *files* that contain `carrot` but the number of *lines*, the same file will be counted multiple times if it contains multiple instances of `carrot`. From `man grep`:

```
    -r, --recursive
          Read all files  under  each  directory,  recursively,  following
          symbolic  links  only  if they are on the command line.  This is
          equivalent to the -d recurse option.
   -i, --ignore-case
          Ignore  case  distinctions  in  both  the  PATTERN and the input
          files.  (-i is specified by POSIX.)
   -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.
```

---

If you really, really want to do it with find, you could do

```
find . -type f -exec grep -im 1 carrot {} \; | wc -l
```

Note that I am specifying `-type f` since you don't want to `grep` directories.

Comment: This isn't correct. Providing `-m 1` will stop after one match, not one match per file. So this will actually always return 1. I think the second solution does it correctly though.

Comment: @Phonon no it won't, try it. At least on my Linux system, it finds the first match in each file. `grep -r` still deals with individual files, it doesn't just `cat` all of them.

Answer (score 4):

Find the number of files contain the word *carrot*

```
number_of_files=`grep -l -r -i "carrot" . | wc -l`
```

Meaning for the `grep` arguments:

```
-l, --files-with-matches
         Only the names of files containing selected lines are written to standard output.  grep will only search a file until a match has been found, making
         searches potentially less expensive.  Pathnames are listed once per file searched.  If the standard input is searched, the string ``(standard
         input)'' is written.

-R, -r, --recursive
         Recursively search subdirectories listed.

-i : case insenstive
```

`wc -l` : prints out the number of lines passed as input to the program. In our case, these lines are the names of files with matching input pattern found by `grep`.

Print the output

```
echo $number_of_files
```

Comment: @Downvoter care to comment the reason ?

Comment: I did not downvote but this does not count the number of files that contain a string, it counts the number of lines that contain it. If a file has three lines that match the pattern you are searching for, it will be counted three times. Also, you don't need the `wc` since `grep` has the `-c` option. Add `-c` and `-m 1` to avoid duplicate matches.

Comment: @terdon: I do not have enough reputation to comment on your answer. So, I am putting it here, OP needs the total number of files that contain the word "carrot". Your `grep -ircm 1 carrot .` doesn't give the number of files that contain a string. Instead, -c option provides the number of matches for the searched pattern it found per file basis . Example; `filename1:count` `filename2:count` . I am unsure your answer is going to be useful for the purpose requested by OP

Comment: @terdon: Additionally with `grep -ircm 1 carrot .`, grep prints out file names even if it doesn't contain `carrot` with zero as count like : `file_name1:0` `file_name2:0`

Comment: You're quite right, serves me right for posting too quickly, thanks. `-l` is better than `-m` as well but hey, I'll stick with my way since you're already using it :)

Answer (score 3):

A variant of smRaj's solution would be a double invocation of grep. The following would give the same result as **grep** [*etc*] **| wc -l**:

```
grep -l -r -i "carrot" . | grep -c .
```

The following would print a numbered list of the files containing the searched word.

```
grep -l -r -i "carrot" . | grep -n .
```

Comment: +1 I was going to answer the exact some thing when I saw that you already have :)